# Translate delegate{} in "public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent = delegate { }" to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, memory-leaks, c#-to-vb.net

I have a question about this article:
http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/09/event-subscribtion-and-memory-leaks-yet-again/

I have memory leaks in vb.net with events. I view my application with the memory profiler and it says my problem are the events :-(

Now I've found this article and I'd like to try it. But I don't know what `delegate{}` in 
`public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent = delegate { };` means.

Comment: Note that you don't have to do a null check in VB.Net like you usually do in C# when raising events.

Answer (score 3):

It's just an empty event handler, that exists (therefore doesn't need to be checked for `null`) but does nothing. The following code snippets are basically the same:

```
// An anonymous delegate (your example):
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent = delegate { };

// The same function using Lambda:
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent = (sender, e) => { };

// A similar function using a named method:
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent = Handler;
private static void Handler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) { }
```

**Translated to VB.Net:**

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Event MyEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    // The following sub is the empty delegate
    Private Sub Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                        Handles Me.MyEvent
        // empty
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: +1 But You don't *need* to do this in VB at all! TheRaiseEvent keyword does the null check for you. C# is so verbose <g>

Comment: Actually, no, these are ***not*** the same. If you check the IL, your last version creates a new delegate-object *per instance*. The anonymous method version has a static field to *cache* the delegate-object, so only only delegate is created... i.e. 27 objects share the same `{}` delegate, but 27 objects have 27 delegates to `Handler`.

Answer (score 1):

That is just a sneaky way of avoiding having to do a null-check on events; basically, it uses an anonymous method as the initial value, but that method *doesn't do anything*. As an implementation detail, this empty delegate instance actually gets cached in a static field, so it doesn't have a huge impact per instance.

If you don't want to worry about the `{}`, then just leave it off:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

and do the null-checks!

Comment: You don't need to do the null (Nothing) checks in VB.NET. The `RaiseEvent` keyword does it for you.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm aware of that, but the code in the question also won't compile in VB ;p